# "Latex" text added to document knitted with bookdown to pdf

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown, flextable

I am producing a pdf with `bookdown`.  I want to create a landscape page for a wide table. When I do this I am getting some odd added text either side of my table: “‘=latex.

````
---
title: "PAV results"
header-includes: \usepackage{pdflscape}
date: "2023-06-19"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    number_sections: no
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: no
---
  
```{r setup2, include=FALSE}
  library(knitr)
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = F, message = F)
  library(dplyr)
  library(flextable)
    library(ftExtra)
```
Intro text


\begin{landscape}

```{r anthro, eval= T}
flextable(anthrotab)%>%autofit()%>%theme_booktabs(bold_header = T)%>%
  set_caption(as_paragraph("My table"))%>%
  align(align = "left", part = "body")%>%
  colformat_md()%>%
   add_footer_lines(as_paragraph("Abbreviations:"))

```

\end{landscape}

text
````

This is how it appears in my pdf:

[image]

This appears to be an issue with `flextable`.

This is another attempt using `kable` and including the flextable table on a portrait page:

````
Intro text


\begin{landscape}

```{r kable}
kbl(anthrotab)
```
\end{landscape}

text

```{r anthro, eval= T}
flextable(anthrotab)%>%autofit()%>%theme_booktabs(bold_header = T)%>%
  set_caption(as_paragraph("My table"))%>%
  align(align = "left", part = "body")%>%
  colformat_md()%>%
   add_footer_lines(as_paragraph("Abbreviations:"))

```
````

which produces [this](https://github.com/mdaviesgit/queries/blob/main/checker.pdf)

Comment: Can you try with `\landscape ... \endlandscape`?

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/705252/36296

Comment: Can you add a compilable [mre]? I get an error about `anthrotab` not found when trying to use your code.

Comment: Adding some kind of data frame as anthrotab (`anthrotab <- tibble(...)`) Is possible reproduce the problem that happen because, for some reason, that R chunk spoils the conversion when nested in some  LaTeX environments (not only landscape), that seems like a package bug (don't happen making the same table with `xtable`, for instance) but anyway it can be solved as suggested in the first comment.